# Writing a custom RotatingFileHandler that rotates logs every day

Tags: python, django, logging, rotation

I am developing a Django application, and would like a custom handler that rotates the log everyday - I've struggled with the TimedRotatingFileHandler (the infamous 'midnight' confusion).

The handler needs to rotate the log file based on the current system date - i.e., a new log file for each day. How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with midnight rotation?

Comment: In case of midnight rotation, the application needs to be running at midnight for the rotation to happen. In my scenario, my application might not run on the weekends. So on a Tuesday, I'd still like to see log files with Friday's and Monday's dates in their filenames.

Comment: Is it running in the background on weekends? Otherwise, I would imagine `TimedRotatingFileHandler` to use the current date.

Comment: It doesn't run on the weekends at all. However, TimedRotatingFileHandler seems to be creating files with mismatching content and filenames. For example, though the filename is appended with `2013-04-28`, it contains logs from 29th April as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution for me would be to just build the log file name with the date. I've done this.

```
'handlers': {
                'default': {
                           'level':'DEBUG',
                           'class':'logging.FileHandler',
                           'filename': '/path/debug_' + date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y') + '.log',
                           'formatter':'standard',
                           },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a POSIX platform using Python >= 2.6 you could use an external log rotator (e.g. `logrotate`) together with a [`WatchedFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler).